# How to alter my mod rewrite rules so that I can achieve this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ /index.php?go=$1 [L]
```

There is one rule to add www to the domain if the user just types `example.com` and the other is just for handling includes.

Now let's say I want to access the URL `anything` (or any other name).

When I enter these URLs they work just fine:

- `www.example.com/anything/` stays the same. Perfect.
- `www.example.com/anything` redirects to `www.example.com/anything/`. Perfect.
- `example.com/anything` redirects to `www.example.com/anything/` Perfect.

**The one thing that doesn't work:**

- `example.com/anything/` changes the URL to `www.example.com/index.php?go=anything`

but I want it to redirect to `www.example.com/anything/` as well.

Does anyone know how to change the rules so that it works too?

Comment: [You don't a actually need `mod_rewrite` to do most of this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

Comment: Is `/private/` a real directory?

Comment: @anubhava No, not necessarily. I just want the URLs to display `www.example.com/anything/` instead of `www.example.com/index.php?go=anything`. Where go=anything leads is defined in index.php. It can be in a directory (for example `./anything/anything.php`), but doesn't have to be. It's just about the URL style

Comment: Yes I understood your requirements. But I don't see any rule here adding trailing slash to make `www.example.com/anything` into `www.example.com/anything/` (where `anything` is not a directory). In case you have more rules in .htaccess then post it here.

Comment: @anubhava This is my entire original .htaccess file (except for the domain) http://pastebin.com/FzkyWNxm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?go=403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?go=404
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ /index.php?go=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $0 ^download/([^/.]+)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ /index.php?go=dl&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $0 ^games/([^/.]+)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ /index.php?go=games&game=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $0 ^tools/([^/.]+)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ /index.php?go=tools&tool=$2 [L]

RewriteCond $0 ^misc/([^/.]+)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ /index.php?go=misc&misc=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Remember to keep redirect rules before internal rewrite ones.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: Use a different browser to test it OR clear your browser cache.

Comment: Cleared my browser cache and now it's working. Thank you so much!